# Realidad Aumentada con django

Tags: python, django

Estoy aprendiendo sobre realidad aumentada y lo estoy aplicando en un proyecto. 
Para ello consulto si es posible hacer uso de la realidad aumentada en Django.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Amigol, pon mas descritivia tu pregunta, sino, mejor elimínala.

Answer (score 1):

La realidad aumentada es el término que se usa para definir una visión a través de un dispositivo tecnológico a un entorno físico del mundo real.

Django es un framework de desarrollo web ([página oficial de django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)) como lo dice su página oficial, si deseas realizar aplicaciones de realidad aumentada te recomendaría aplicaciones nativas ya sea para Android o IOS.